# ODOO_11 onchange message_send

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

Good day to all.

I strucked with problem in ODOO and both google and SO can't give me answer.
I try to use message_post method in onchange function, like

```
@api.onchange('approver')
def approve_send_message(self):
    self.message_post(body='Another bit of test')
```

But message didn't appear(but create with no model and id in it).
When I try to use thing like

```
self.env['my.model'].browse([1]).message_post(body='body')
```

it works fine.
General question - how to get id of object, in which onchange raised?
Things like _origin, origin, context and self.id didn't work. And self.id return

```
odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7f6eaa69a2e8
```

insted of ID.
Thanx for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Found reason - when ODOO do onchange it create new object, with all params of old one, plus changes. Old params stored in obj.orign param, but not the id. 
I found some wierd and sometimes not working methods to find old id, but there is no normal way i found. So, i think, this is one of the things that must be implemented in ODOO.